# Doing custom avatars with nodejs

Tags: node.js, png

So I'm wondering if this http://bokehman.com/do_it_yourself_avatars/ is also possible in nodejs.

Basically I want to make a png out of several other pngs (all the same size) that are just stacked one over each other and then save it on the server.

Can I do that? A short example would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. A "short example" would not be very helpful in your quest. It is better if you learn how to use to tools.

First you need to familiarize yourself with a module like `gm` that will help you interface with the imagemagick library : https://github.com/aheckmann/gm

Then you will need to learn how to blend and or compose images together with imagemagick: for example see http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#blend

Comment: Thanks, Nice I will check them and learn how to use them. Thank you once again.